# Stuck on a list example on Zybooks for Python

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a problem on Zybooks and here is the problem and the code that they provide you with. The language is Python.

Assign `sum_extra` with the total extra credit received given *list* `test_grades`. Full credit is `100`, so anything over `100` is extra credit. For the given program, `sum_extra` is `8`because `1 + 0 + 7 + 0 is 8`.

Sample output for the given program:

*Sum extra: 8*

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]
sum_extra = -999 # Initialize 0 before your loop

'''Enter your code here'''

print('Sum extra:', sum_extra)
```

This is last attempt:

```
for i in range(len(test_grades)): 
    sum_exta = 100 - int(test_grades)
```

I just don't know how to continue further on with that code. I'm just lost.

Comment: why `sum_extra` has value `-999`?

Comment: Your code seems simply like setup code. There isn't an actual attempt here. Can you show your latest attempt on how you tried to calculate for the extra credits?

Comment: It is pretty straightforward, take 100 away from any grade > 100 and sum all those values. You should make an attempt with that information. If you get stuck come back and ask a question  but that should make it pretty easy to implement.

Comment: for i in range(len(test_grades)):
    sum_exta = 100 - int(test_grades)

Comment: That was my last attempt I guess, I just don't know how to continue further on with that code. I'm just lost.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, try `sum` function and *"list comprehension"* with condition:

```
test_grades = [101, 83, 107, 90]

sum_extra = sum([grade - 100 for grade in test_grades if grade > 100])
print(sum_extra)   # 8
```

Or we can use *generator expression* when all we need is iterating once(without further list usage):

```
sum_extra = sum(grade - 100 for grade in test_grades if grade > 100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was just confused about how lists worked exactly but now understand after seeing the answer.

Comment: I *think* it might be faster to use a generator expression here.